# How to get rid of Microsoft Authenticator?

Tags: uninstallation, microsoft-authenticator

I have Office 365 subscription and it works well. However, I got the Microsoft Authenticator app installed on my Samsung Galaxy and it got my Outlook account added there. I have no idea how that happened since I did not add it.

I've read the instructions from [How to use the Microsoft Authenticator app](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026727/microsoft-account-how-to-use-the-microsoft-authenticator-app), but the instructions are complicated. I don't need this Authenticator, so I want to get rid of it.

How can I get rid of it and keep my Microsoft account?

Answer (score 1):

You must both delete the app from your old device and tell Microsoft to forget the old device and unregister it from your account. From [Common questions about the Microsoft Authenticator app](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/common-questions-about-the-microsoft-authenticator-app-12d283d1-bcef-4875-9ae5-ac360e2945dd):

> - To remove the app from a device using a personal Microsoft account. Go to the two-step verification area of your [Account Security](https://account.microsoft.com/security) page and choose to turn off verification for your old device.

Then you can uninstall the app just like any other app.